# How to loop through multiple variables for a mysqli join query in php

Tags: php, html, post, join, mysqli

I currently have a webpage setup with a textarea that should be used to enter in a variable(s) to then be used in a subsequent mysqli query. The query does a couple joins in the database and then lists the results in a table. How would I be able to enter multiple entries in the textarea to do the query multiple times and list all results in the table?

-- also, would it be possible to have the textarea entry go to different variables based on the text format: i.e. if the entry is letters/numbers -> $variable1, if the entry is dbname:(letters/numbers) -> $variable2 so then I could have multiple "WHERE" clauses be specified by different variables matching in different columns.

The code is below:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Header</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
    body {
        background-color: ;
    }
</style>
<body>

    <style>
        h1 {
            text-align: center;
        }
        h3 {
            text-align: center;
        }
        h5 {
            text-align: center;
        }
        #panel {
            min-height: 800px;
        }
        #search {
            display: inline-block;
        }
    </style>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <h1>Header</h1>
            <hr/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <div id="panel" class="panel">
                <div id="search" class="large-4 columns">

                    <form align="center" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">

                        <label>Insert Data
                            <textarea rows="25" name="variable"><?php echo $variable ?></textarea>
                        </label>

                        <input align="left" type="submit" name="query" value="Results" class="small radius button"></input>

                    </form>
                </div>

                <table align="center" role="grid">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>1</th>
                            <th>2</th>
                            <th>3</th>
                            <th>4</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                        <?php

                            $variable = test_input($_POST['variable']);

                            function test_input($data) {
                                $data = trim($data);
                                $data = stripslashes($data);
                                $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
                                return $data;
                            }

                            if(isset($_POST['query'])){

                                $mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "password", "dbname");
                                if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
                                    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
                                }

                                echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";

                                $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT a.1, a.2, b.3, g.4 FROM alpha a LEFT OUTER JOIN beta b ON a.1 = b.1 LEFT OUTER JOIN gamma g ON a.1 = g.1 WHERE a.1='$variable';");
                                if (!$result) {
                                    echo "Database Query Failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
                                }
                                $i = 0;
                                while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {

                                    $class = ($i == 0) ? "" : "alt";
                                    echo "<tr class=\"".$class."\">";
                                    echo "<tr>";
                                        echo "<td>" .$row["1"]. "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" .$row["2"]. "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" .$row["3"]. "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" .$row["4"]. "</td>";
                                    echo "</tr>";
                                    $i = ($i==0) ? 1:0;
                                }

                                $mysqli->close();

                            }

                        ?>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out by looping with

```
$variable = explode("\n", $_POST['variable']);
```